# Weird timezone issue

Tags: php, mysql

So when I run

```
SELECT NOW()
```

I get

```
2021-01-09 21:30:00
```

When I run

```
SET time_zone = '-0:00';
SELECT NOW()
```

I get

```
2021-01-09 18:30:00
```

When I save something to my table via PHP data() in the DATETIME type column, I get

```
2021-01-09 18:30:00
```

Next, when I run

```
SET time_zone = '-0:00';
select * from ip_logging where DATE(date) > now() - interval 100 minute
```

I get nothing. If I don't use "SET time_zone" - same thing.

But when I run

```
SET time_zone = '-0:00';
select * from ip_logging where DATE(date) > now() - interval 1000 minute
```

I get my results in the interval of 1000 minutes (even tho my last row is saved 1 minute ago)

What am I doing wrong here?....

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to get rows added in the last 10 minutes:

```
SET time_zone = '-0:00';
SELECT * FROM ip_logging WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```